# Convergence of random variables approximation

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to understand the convergence of random variables and to prove an equivalent criterion for point wise convergence, For starters, we now that if $(X_i)_{i\ge 1}$ is a sequence of random variables and $A:=\{\lim_i X_i\text{ exists}\}$, then $X_i$ converges a.s. if $P(A)=1$.
We can represent $A$ in the following way using Cauchy criterion

$$ A=\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{m\ge 1}\bigcap_{i,j\ge m}\{|X_i-X_j|\le{k^{-1}}\} $$
and thus this set has probability 1. I am trying to prove the following approximation of the limit set $A$. That is for all $\varepsilon>0$, we can choose $k,m,n\ge 1$ such that the sets $A_{k,m,n}=\bigcap_{n\le i,j\le m}\{|X_i-X_j|\le k^{-1}\}$ approximate $A$. More precisely, $P(A\backslash A_{k,m,n})<\varepsilon$ and $P(A_{k,m,n}\backslash A)<\varepsilon$. However, i am unsure on how to prove such a result, as I have no information on the actual measure of the limiting set $A$.